# Using complete the square to determine positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, bilinear-form, positive-definite

I realize this may be a basic question but I am having trouble following my notes.
I have the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}16&12\\12&9\end{bmatrix} .$$ So I've got my equation from the matrix to be $(16x)^2 - 12xy - 12yx + 9y^2.$ Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The bilinear form is $16x^2+24xy+9y^2$. And since this is equal to $\left(4x+3y\right)^2$, your bilinear form is *not* definite positive.

Comment: I have been in the middle of editing in large additions to my own answers when someone does a minor correction like that, and it disturbs everything, because now I have to load what they changed, and then add the extra onto that instead. One time the edit was wrong and what I had written before was correct, and I lost a few minutes of typing nonetheless. This is one reason why I _almost never_ edit answers. It's much better in my opinion to leave a comment and let the owner of the answer take care of it in their own time.

Comment: how are you converting the biliniar form to (4x+3y)^2

Comment: @JPRP I am not sure that I understood your question. All I did was to use the fact that$$(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):16x^2+24xy+9y^2=(4x+3y)^2.$$

Comment: say I have 16x2-24xy+10y^2. How would I factor that?

Comment: @JPRP Since $16x^2-24xy+10y^2=(4x-3y)^2+y^2$, then the bilinear form *is* positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

Since $16>0$, but $16\cdot 9-12^2=0$, the  matrix is only positive semidefinite, but not positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

The direction that would usually be called completing the square is
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 12 \\ 
12 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

which means semidefinite, not definite. In particular
$$ 16 (x + \frac{3}{4}y)^2 = 16x^2 + 24 xy + 9 y^2 $$

=================================

$$  D_0 = H $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 12 \\ 
12 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 12 \\ 
12 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
16 & 12 \\ 
12 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$